# Uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails i'm getting the error `uninitialized constant CartController::EXPRESS_CHECKOUT` while i'm calling the method `express_checkout` of the controller `CartController`, i think that the problem is in config/environments/development.rb file, because i defined

```
config.after_initialize do          
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

    paypal_options = {
            login: "<mail>",
            password: "<pass>",
            signature: "<sig>"
    }

    ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = 
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
    end
```

But even if i tried to change something in this file, i can't fix this error.

This is the code of cart_controller.rb

```
def express_checkout
        response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(params[:amount], ip: request.remote_ip, return_url: "http://localhost:8080/checkout_details", cancel_return_url: "http://localhost:8080", currency: "EUR", allow_guest_checkout: true, items: [{name: "Order", description: "Order description", quantity: "1", amount: params[:amount]}]
        )
        redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
    end

    def checkout_details
        @token = params[:token]
        @payer_id = params[:PayerID]
        @details = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.details_for(@token)
    end

    def purchase
        @t = params[:token]
        @p = params[:PayerID]
        @result = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(params[:amount], {:token => @t, :payer_id => @p, :currency => "EUR"})
    end
```

I checked the version of the gem `activemerchant` and is version `1.66.0`, so the version of this gem is not a problem.
Anyone knows something about this?

Comment: Could you add the source code for the `CartController` to the question?

Comment: Done! Let me know if you need something else

Comment: It looks like Rails searches for the `EXPRESS_GATEWAY` constant in the controller namespace. Have you tried to call `::EXPRESS_GATEWAY` in the action? Otherwise, it looks like the constant isn't getting initialized. I would recommend you to create an initializer file in the `config/initializers` directory and initialize it there.

Comment: I tried, but instead of `uninitialized constant CartController::EXPRESS_CHECKOUT`, i get `uninitialized constant EXPRESS_GATEWAY`

Comment: Have you restarted the rails server?

Comment: I did it, now it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tobias suggested me, i corrected the mistake in `CartController.rb`, modifying `EXPRESS_GATEWAY` in `::EXPRESS_GATEWAY`. After this change, i restarted the rails server and everything works perfectly!